# Django unit test on custom model manager method

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am pretty new in python and django.

I have model with custom model manager with a method ,where i am raising 
`ValidationError` on some exceptions.now i want to test this custom manager method.but don't know how to catch `ValidationError` or anyother error in terms of testing django model's customs manager method.

My scenario is depicted below,

```
class CustomModelManager(model.Manager):

    def custom_method(self):
        #for some exception
        raise ValidationError('a sample validation error')

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    ###fields
    objects = CustomModelManager()
```

i have tried the following unit test,but its not working ,

```
def test_samle_model(self):
    issues = Issues.objects.custom_method(field1='wrong field')###this will raise that validationError
    self.assertEqualValidationError, 'a sample validation error')
```

is it possible to catch 'any error' to test? or am i missing something?

Comment: Why would you raise a ValidationErrom from a Manager? That belongs in a validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`assertRaises'](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
def test_sample_model(self):
     with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):    
         issues = Issues.objects.custom_method(field1='wrong field')
```

Answer (score 2):

use [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

```
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
   issues = Issues.objects.custom_method(field1='wrong field')
```